# Java Generics bounded wild card usages before the return type of a method

Tags: java, generics

In the class below, in method m1, is there really any use of mentioning `K extends Runnable`before the method return type? I cannot return anything other than `Collection<K>` anyways. And if I want to return any subclass of Runnable I would have specified the method like,

```
static <T> Collection<? extends Runnable> m1(ArrayList<T> l)
```

Does the `K extends Runnable` before the method return type have any significance at all? I get no compilation error for this code either

```
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Thread> l = new ArrayList<>();
        l.add(new Thread());
        l.add(new Thread());
        m1(l);
    }

     static <T, K extends Runnable> Collection<K> m1(ArrayList<T> l) {
        ArrayList<K> r = new ArrayList<>();
        return r;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your proposed version (`static <T> Collection<K extends Runnable> m1(ArrayList<T> l)` compile? Can you introduce type variables like that?

Comment: Yes, I dont get any compilation error.

Comment: `static <T, K extends Runnable> Collection<K> m1(ArrayList<T> l)` lets the caller of the method decide what `K` should be. So that you can get back a `Collection<Runnable>` or a `Collection<Thread>` or a `Collection<MyTask>`. (But I don't see how that can work unless the result is empty, as it is here. How is `m1` at runtime supposed to know about `K`?

Comment: What is your Java version? And can you show your proposed class in full? `public class Test {
    static <T> Collection<K extends Runnable> m1(ArrayList<T> l) {
        return null;
    }
}
` does not compile for me.

Comment: I see you are using <K extends Runnable> while I'm using <? extends Runnable> with only <T> before the return type in my method. Im practising Generics by writing test classes of my own and learning from my mistakes. I'm using open jdk 8 on RHEL 7. The IDE I'm on is, Intellij IDE.

Comment: I just realized you have a K in there even while you asked if it compiled. Sorry I did not pay attention

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By having the parameter `K`, you can let the caller decide what kind of collection it wants back:

```
public class Test {
    static <T, K extends Runnable> Collection<K> m1(ArrayList<T> l) {
        ArrayList<K> r = new ArrayList<>();
        return r;
    }

    static void callingIt(){
        ArrayList<?> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Collection<Thread> threads = m1(list);
        Collection<Runnable> runnables = m1(list);
        Collection<MyTask> special = m1(list);

    }

    class MyTask extends Thread{}
}
```

If you only had `Collection<? extends Runnable>` then the caller cannot get back a `Collection<Thread>`.

But unless the `K` is connected to something else, I cannot see how this would work except for empty result lists (because as soon as you want to add something to `r`, you will have to make sure it is an instance of `K`).

---

You can see this pattern being used in `Collections.emptyList`:

```
public static final List EMPTY_LIST = new EmptyList<>();

public static final <T> List<T> emptyList() {
    return (List<T>) EMPTY_LIST;
}
```

The method returns the same thing as the field, but because it is a method, the caller can use it to produce generically typed lists of any type (whereas the field cannot be flexible like this).

There is an unchecked cast in there (with a warning), but since the list is empty, we (unlike the compiler) know it is safe.

Comment: Thanks @Thilo. If I had not specifed `K extends Runnable` in the method `static <T, K extends Runnable> Collection<K> m1(ArrayList<T> l)` and had it as, `static <T> Collection<K> m1(ArrayList<T> l)` the caller can still assign the results of method call `m1` to  `Collection<Thread>` or `Collection <Runnable>` or `Collection<Anything>` correct? The only typesafety (with `K extends Runnable`)is I can be sure that the return Collection holds one of `Runnable` or its child classes but that does not stop me from returning a `List<Number>` from `m1` and there is no compile time type safety yet

Comment: I have read generics type are invariant. List<Animal>= List<Dog> will thrown an error. But the code in your answer above looks to me like this is violated although not directly.The method says K is a Runnable or a sub class of Runnable. The caller assigns this to Collection<Thread> or Collection<Runnable> or Collection<MyThread> and the compiler does not complain. Is it not the same case as List<Dog> or List<Cat> assigned to List<Animal>. The only difference I see between them is how the type is specified but I'd think it must still be an error. correct?

Comment: The difference is that if the method says `public <X> List<X> foo()` the *caller* can freely decide the type. So this can make a `List<Dog>` or a `List<Cat>`. If the method is typed `public List<Animal> foo()` or `public List<Dog> foo()` then the type is fixed, and the caller has to accept that (in an invariant way).

Comment: "In fact, you cannot even get back a `Collection<Runnable>`, so this is a pretty useless declaration." It's not useless -- they get back a `Collection<? extends Runnable>`, from which they can get elements of type `Runnable` out of it.